# Could I know, inside the controller, the current URL?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

There's a way of know the current URL on a controller at Laravel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following function from the `Request` class.

`Request::url()`

Answer (score 0):

Try $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].

If you need more than just the current URI, you can find all of the pieces on the $_SERVER array. The documentation on that array: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: This is not the "Laravel way" of doing it!

Comment: This is true. It's more of the PHP way. By all means, use the Laravel functions for all that you can.

Answer (score 0):

URL::current() does what you're looking for I believe.